# Why does my code not work on a device, but work on the emulator?

Tags: android, sqlite

My code works well on emulator, but not on device. Error in no such method query.

```
package testing.login;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        //Create database
        super(context, "MyDatabase.db", null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Create tables
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ANDRO(ID INTEGER,NAME TEXT,ADDRESS TEXT);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE QUESTIONS(ID INTEGER,QUESTION TEXT,OPTION_A                     TEXT,OPTION_B TEXT,OPTION_C TEXT,OPTION_D TEXT,ANSWER TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        //Delete tables
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists ANDRO");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists QUESTION");
    }

}

package testing.login;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Declaring Variables
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    EditText name, address;
    String sname, saddress;
    boolean namenotequal = true;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    DatabaseBean dbb;
    boolean upwrong = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getBaseContext()); //Accesing Database helper class
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //On click function of sign up button
    public void signup(View view) {
        dbHelper.close();
        //Intent used to access sign up class
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Signup.class);
        //      intent.putExtra("sachithkn", dbHelper);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {}

    //On click function of sign in button
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public void signin(View view) {

        //Reading values from text fields
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        sname = name.getText().toString();
        saddress = address.getText().toString();

        //Encrypting password using md5
        saddress = Signup.md5(saddress);
        String[] values = new String[] {
            "ID",
                "NAME",
                "ADDRESS"
        };

        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //Opening database
        if (sname.equals("") || saddress.equals("")) //Checking whether text fields are empty or not
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be empty", 2000).show();
        else {
            //Reading values from database
            Cursor cursor = db.query(false, "ANDRO", values, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String dbname = cursor.getString(1);
                    String dbaddress = cursor.getString(2);

                    if (dbname.equals(sname) && dbaddress.equals(saddress)) //Checking whether values are in database or not
                    {
                        upwrong = false; //Variable set to run toast correctly
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have successfully logedin", 2000).show();
                        dbHelper.close();
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Questions.class); //Accesing questions activity
                        intent2.putExtra("passname", dbname);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                if (upwrong) //Variable set to run toast correctly          
                {
                    //Toast set to show when password or user name is wrong
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong  username or password ,Try again", 2000).show();
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
02-16 12:34:44.804: W/dalvikvm(26832): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 255: Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;.query (ZLjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;)Landroid/database/Cursor;
02-16 12:34:44.804: D/dalvikvm(26832): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x007f
02-16 12:34:44.804: D/dalvikvm(26832): VFY: dead code 0x0082-00e8 in Ltesting/login/MainActivity;.signin (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-16 12:34:47.929: W/dalvikvm(26832): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 255: Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;.query (ZLjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;)Landroid/database/Cursor;
02-16 12:34:47.929: D/dalvikvm(26832): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0077
02-16 12:34:47.929: D/dalvikvm(26832): VFY: dead code 0x007a-00ec in Ltesting/login/Signup;.signup (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-16 12:34:57.148: D/AndroidRuntime(26832): Shutting down VM
02-16 12:34:57.148: W/dalvikvm(26832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    ... 11 more
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    at testing.login.MainActivity.signin(MainActivity.java:77)
02-16 12:34:57.195: E/AndroidRuntime(26832):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? *(Edit: I've fixed it for you)*

Comment: Next time, please make an effort to format your code readably, rather than having the [indenting mess](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21808611/1) that was there before I cleaned it up for you.

Comment: Is this db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE QUESTIONS(ID INTEGER,QUESTION TEXT,OPTION_A    (**incomplete sql and open string**) your **real code**?! Do you expect it to compile??

Comment: sorry Artoo detoo .My coping got some error in arrangement.Actually you can see the code after it when you drag horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short, you code is running an API version that is not supported by the emulator.

your query is [supported from API 16](http://tinyurl.com/nvbwbze), try using the other query method

Comment: thank you i solve it by changing query to raw query.This error is showing in android 4.0.3 also.I dont know why?